# Why onStop() is called after onCreate() when starting an Activity within onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the following workflow:

- startActivityForResult(Activity1)
- finish() called on Activity1 (when pushing a button)
- onActivityResult() ==> startActivityForResult(Activity2)

===> Activity2.onCreate() is called before Activity1.onStop()

Why I have that?

**Edited:**

Here is the code:

1- MainActivity.java

```
    // On click on a button
    public void start(View view) {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(activityIntent, 0);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, 
            int resultCode, 
            Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
                startActivityForResult(activityIntent, 0);
            }
```

2- Activity2.java

```
// A button to finish the activity
public void stop(View view) {
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

3- Activity3.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity3);
}
```

Comment: could you share some code? Also, onPause is always called when activity changes, onStop, not so.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: My question is why Activity2.onCreate() is called before Activity1.onStop() ?

Comment: Just curious - are you in a situation where this behavior is causing you problems, our do you just want to understand why it happens?

Comment: Maybe the activity is not completely obscured by another activity?

Comment: @Kevin I want to understand why it happens like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of the lifecycle.  onStop isn't called until after an Activity is removed from view.  So onStop won't be called until something else is blocking it from the user-  activity2 in this case.  That means Activity2 will already have to have been created, because you can't block another activity if you don't exist.

Comment: Good comment. Makes sense since the Activity needs to run before it blocks right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I want to understand the behavior. I Updated my question with some code. It seems to me weird that onCreate() is called before onStop().

Comment: Because activity1 won't stop() until activity 2 start() is ready to be called.  That requires activity2.onCreate to be called already.